# Modelagem de banco de dados com entidades para histórico

Tags: banco-de-dados, log, histórico

No sistema que estou desenvolvendo existem diversas partes que irão precisar 
de histórico dos dados.

Como eu fiz até aqui foi, para quando precisar de um histórico para uma tabela criei uma outra tabela com os mesmos campos e mais um campo relacionando a tabela origem.

Até agora vem dando funcionando.

Dois problemas que tenho com essa abordagem são:

1) Quanto mais tabelas precisam de histórico, mais tabelas tenho que replicar e também acaba precisando fazer os cuidados nos códigos;

2) O crescimento de dados para essas tabelas é enorme;

Quais melhores abordagens para esse caso?

Comment: Depende dos requisitos que não foram postados. Todos eles, sem esquecer de nenhum.

Comment: Quanto ao item dois um particionamento da tabela é uma opção de solução.

Answer (score -1):

Ja passei por esse tipo de problema, chegando a auditoria ocupar 90% dos dados em storage.
Nesse caso utilizamos a opção de expurgo por período, você define uma forma para gravar os dados ou em arquivos(arquivos txt, csv ou json) ou em um outro servidor, que você exporte os dados e remova da sua base liberando espaço e isso tem que ser definido de forma periódica, tipo 3 em 3 meses ou quando o volume de dados chegar num ponto de controle que você ache correto remover.
Com o advento do Big Data, em muitos casos esses históricos são enviados para um data store ou data lake.
Espero ter ajudado.